# HTML Range styling firefox. Get the thumb to center over edges

Tags: html, css, firefox

Im trying to style a input[type=range] and have accomplished what im trying to do regarding chrome and safari, but Im struggling a bit to achieve what I want for Firefox. In Chrome / Safari Im able to use ::before pseudo selectors to create a tear drop shape thumb to drag the slider, but the ::before selector does not work on input elements in firefox. Thus, I have to style the thumb itself.

The thumb looks like it should, but when you slide it all the way to the left, or to the right, its the edges of the tear drop that stops. I need it to go 15px over on each side of the slider, so that its the "pointy" part that indicates the current position on the slider.

I have tried just about anything with positioning, and margins now without success. Does anyone here have any tips? Here is a jsFiddle for it: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLr26rvw/2/)

Here is the CSS code I've used to style the thumb:

```
.ep-calc-tools-section .ep-calc-tool input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #3D3F44;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50%;
    border: 3px solid #3D3F44;
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(-30px) rotate(224deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out the "correct" answer to this as well. One thing you can do, is set the width and height of the thumb to 0, so it appears very small, then add scale() to your transform rule to set the size of it.

```
/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
.ep-calc-tools-section .ep-calc-tool input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    background: #3D3F44;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50%;
    border: 3px solid #3D3F44;
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(-30px) rotate(224deg) scale(6);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jLr26rvw/3/

Comment: Thanks Danny. If its the "correct" way or not, it worked. I have a feeling most solutions to style the thumb, or slider at the moment is very hackish anyhow, since all browser treat it differently and you have to apply custom rules for almost all of them anyhow.

Comment: the concept works, thanks! I had to use width/height of 1 to be able to properly scale and with a little fiddling I was able to get back box-shadow that was messed after the transition

Comment: UPDATE: scaling is a bit different on every zoom/DPI setting, the smaller width/height before scaling, the bigger difference